# How can you get a list of the datasources used to generate a page in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When you add a debug IP to review the debug information from the collection of templates that are parsed to present the page, it includes a list of all queries from that page.

Is it possible to get access to that object for inspection?

I'm looking at trying to automate the documentation which data sources are in use for which page requests. We have a large number of small web apps that access different databases and have different dependencies. I'm hoping to find a way to automate the documentation of these dependencies rather than having to manually review all code for all of the webapps.

Not sure if the object doesn't get created until after the page creation is too far gone to actually *do* anything with the data, but who knows...

Comment: read the code of http://coldfire.riaforge.org/.  Maybe you'll find a way to do it.

Comment: I believe the information is generated *when* the page executes, so accessing the debugger information may not help you here.

Comment: _"I'm looking at trying to automate the documentation which data sources are in use for which page requests."_ - why?

Comment: Updated question to try to clarify the reason for the request...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet of code that you can add to the end of your template to get a list of datasources used on the page:

```
<cfobject action="CREATE" type="JAVA" class="coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory" name="factory">
<cfset cfdebugger = factory.getDebuggingService()>
<cfset qEvents = cfdebugger.getDebugger().getData()>

<cftry>
    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="cfdebug_qryDSN">
        SELECT DISTINCT DATASOURCE FROM qEvents WHERE type = 'SqlQuery'
    </cfquery>
    <cfcatch type="Any">
        <cfset cfdebug_qryDSN = queryNew('DATASOURCE')>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfdump var="#cfdebug_qryDSN#" label="cfdebug_qryDSN">
```

PS: most of the inspiration for this snippet came from {cfusion 10 home}\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\debug\classic.cfm.  You can get some good ideas on how to gain access to debugger objects/data from this file.

Comment: This works great if debugging is turned on. Any ideas on options to either do this without debugging turned on -- or at least so that the debugging content is not shown to the user? If I have to, I can crawl the site manually (yuck) from my IP with debugging turned on... but this is less automatic by far. Can you turn on debugging programatically INSIDE a page and turn it off again before the content is displayed?

Comment: You can use the Administrator API to programmatically turn debugging on and off, but I am not sure if that will let you get the data you need. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html#WS22A46B0F-C945-444a-8775-BF305446EF86

Comment: The cfdump is in the example just to show how it works.  You could put this in the OnRequestEnd function in Application.cfc and replace the cfdump with code to add the datasources to a database or some other kind of method to retain the information.  Then use a tool like HTTrack to spider the site to capture all the information.

Comment: @Scott Stroz, the admin api will probably work if it is at the beginning of the request (OnRequestStart).  My main complaint with the Admin API is that it conflicts with <cflogin>.  That is, if you have an authenticated user using <cflogin>, the Admin API login over-rides it and replaces it with the administrators credentials.  This can cause very strange results.  I guess my complaint is with <cflogin> it shouldn't share the same authentication space as the Admin API.

Comment: Then don't use `cflogin` ;-) I have never used `cflogin`. Never really saw the need to.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this....

If your [cfroot]/cfusion/lib/neo-datasource.xml file is WDDX encoded and you're not sandboxed, you can use the following (tested on CF2021)

```
<cflock type="readonly" scope="Server" timeout="5">
    <CFSET LibPath=Server.System.Properties["coldfusion.libPath"]>
</cflock>
<CFFILE action="Read" file="#LibPath#/neo-datasource.xml" variable="DatasourcesWDDX">
<cfwddx action="wddx2cfml" input="#DatasourcesWDDX#" output="Datasources">

<cfoutput>#StructKeyList(Datasources[1])#</cfoutput>
<cfdump var=#Datasources#>
```

The first position of the Datasources array holds a structure containing information on each configured datasource with the main key being the name of the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that'll work for each application which uses an `Application.cfc`.

1. `Enable Request Debugging Output` in CF Administrator.
2. Configure `Debugging IP Addresses` so that every page receives debugging information.
3. Assuming that `Select Debugging Output Format` is set to `classic.cfm`, **short circuit** `{cfusion 10 home}\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\debug\classic.cfm` by making `<cfreturn>` the first executable statement in `classic.cfm`.  This will prevent any pages from seeing the debug output.
4. In `Application.cfc::OnRequestEnd()` do what Scott Jibben [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21401952/547904).  You can wrap Scott's idea in an `<cfif IsDebugMode()>`.